# Why loss is remaining constant during training FCN-8s?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, deeplearning4j, matconvnet

I am trying to run FCN-8s. I did the following steps:
1. downloaded [this repository](https://github.com/developmentseed/caffe-fcn) 
2. converting my data to LMDB and changing the paths in train_val.prototxt
3. downloading the fcn8s-heavy-pascal `caffemodel`
4. changing the `number_of_output` in `train_val.prototxt` and `deploy.prototxt` from **60** to **5** (the number of classes in my data) in the last following layers:

```
layer {
  name: "score59"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "score59"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5 #60
    kernel_size: 1
    engine: CAFFE
  }
}
layer {
  name: "upscore2"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "score59"
  top: "upscore2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5 #60
    bias_term: false
    kernel_size: 4
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "score-pool4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool4"
  top: "score-pool4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5 #60
    kernel_size: 1
    engine: CAFFE
  }
}
layer { type: 'Crop' name: 'crop' bottom: 'score-pool4' bottom: 'upscore2'
  top: 'score-pool4c' }
layer {
  name: "fuse"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "upscore2"
  bottom: "score-pool4c"
  top: "score-fused"
  eltwise_param {
    operation: SUM
  }
}
layer {
  name: "upsample-fused-16"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "score-fused"
  top: "score4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5 #60
    bias_term: false
    kernel_size: 4
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "score-pool3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool3"
  top: "score-pool3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5 #60
    kernel_size: 1
    engine: CAFFE
  }
}
layer { type: 'Crop' name: 'crop' bottom: 'score-pool3' bottom: 'score4'
  top: 'score-pool3c' }
layer {
  name: "fuse"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "score4"
  bottom: "score-pool3c"
  top: "score-final"
  eltwise_param {
    operation: SUM
  }
}
layer {
  name: "upsample"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "score-final"
  top: "bigscore"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5 #60
    bias_term: false
    kernel_size: 16
    stride: 8
  }
}
layer { type: 'Crop' name: 'crop' bottom: 'bigscore' bottom: 'data' top: 'score' }
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "score"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  loss_param {
    normalize: false
  }
}
```

I started the training with the weights of pre-trained model for pascal dataset. But the the loss remains constant (loss = 105476) over the time.

```
0112 18:25:07.198588  5878 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 150, lr = 1e-14
I0112 18:26:07.614239  5878 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 200, loss = 105476
I0112 18:26:07.614459  5878 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 105476 (* 1 = 105476 loss)
I0112 18:26:07.614490  5878 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 200, lr = 1e-14
I0112 18:27:06.198556  5878 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 250, loss = 105476
I0112 18:27:06.198801  5878 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 105476 (* 1 = 105476 loss)
I0112 18:27:06.198834  5878 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 250, lr = 1e-14
I0112 18:28:05.056469  5878 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 300, loss = 105476
I0112 18:28:05.056715  5878 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 105476 (* 1 = 105476 loss)
I0112 18:28:05.056751  5878 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 300, lr = 1e-14
I0112 18:29:04.537042  5878 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 350, loss = 105476
I0112 18:29:04.537261  5878 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 105476 (* 1 = 105476 loss)
I0112 18:29:04.537293  5878 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 350, lr = 1e-14
I0112 18:30:05.320504  5878 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 400, loss = 105476
I0112 18:30:05.320751  5878 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 105476 (* 1 = 105476 loss)
I0112 18:30:05.320796  5878 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 400, lr = 1e-14
I0112 18:31:06.690937  5878 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 450, loss = 105476
I0112 18:31:06.691177  5878 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 105476 (* 1 = 105476 loss)
I0112 18:31:06.691207  5878 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 450, lr = 1e-14
I0112 18:32:06.593940  5878 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 500, loss = 105476
I0112 18:32:06.596643  5878 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 105476 (* 1 = 105476 loss)
I0112 18:32:06.596701  5878 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 500, lr = 1e-14
```

I do not know which part I am doing wrong. I really appreciate your help to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you please check which layers have the "does not need backward" statement during initialization? (inside the log, before starting the training phase)

Comment: @LemmRas thanks for your attention. These three in the log `does not need backward computation`: **label** does not need backward computation.
`**data_data_0_split** does not need backward computation`.
`**data** does not need backward computation.` . I added these two lines  **group: 5
    weight_filler: { type: "bilinear" }**  to `Deconvolution` layers, but the problem is still there...Loss remains constant.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you use the function called `surgery.transplant()` in `solve.py` to transplant the caffemodel of original net to your current net?
- Did you add `weight-filler` and `bias-filler` on Deconvolutional layer with initial value in `net.py`?
- After doing these two steps, did you execute the `net.py` to generate a updated layer?

Check these steps, and see what will happen.

Comment: Thanks. I did not change the layers, but `weight-filler` is there. I am a beginner in python and Caffe. I have never used `solve.py` and `net.py`. The only steps that I did is to train the model with `solver.prototxt` and `train_val.prototxt`, I used the snapshot model to infer the test image by using `infer.py` script. However, the output image is always black even after 200000 iterations. Could you please let me know what is the purpose of `surgery.transplant()` and what exactly `solve.py` and `net.py` are doing? in which stage should I run these scripts? Thanks in advance

Comment: surgery.transplant() is used for convey network parameters between different net structures.for example: VGG16 is used as original net structure,you want convey pre-trained parameters on VGG16 to your present network, but your present network has a different structure from VGG16,so you need surgery.transplant('your network','VGG16').

Comment: net.py is used for generate train.prototxt and val.prototxt.
solve.py is used to start training process.
everytime you change net.py,you need to "python net.py" to generate a new train.prototxt and val.prototxt. that means you have changed your net structure.

Comment: And what's more, I see that you want to train FCN-8s directly?Have you ever train a FCN-32S or FCN-16S?If not,you'd better train these two in advance.

Comment: @Ivxubo Thank you very much for your guidance. I trained the FSN32 from scratch for my data.